# How can I use SELECT sub queries in stead of Views in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 database from which I need to extract information about relations between node types "instruments" and "probes". The result I am looking for is a table where the first column is instrument titles, the second one is probe group title followed by probe title, probe subtitle, probe SKU and so forth.

All probes and instruments are interconnected in special group nodes with 2 node reference tables. One for instruments and one for probes. These 2 tables contain entity_id's for the corresponding probes and instruments that can be used together. All titles and node ID's can be found in the node table.

So I have come up with this solution. First I created 3 different views like this:

```
   CREATE VIEW InstrumentTitel AS
        SELECT node.title AS InstrumentTitel ,
        field_data_field_koppla_instrument.entity_id 
        FROM node 
        INNER join field_data_field_koppla_instrument ON node.nid = field_data_field_koppla_instrument.field_koppla_instrument_nid;

    CREATE VIEW givareTitel2 AS
        SELECT 
        node.title AS GivareTitel ,
        field_data_field_koppla_givare.entity_id, 
        node.nid 
        FROM node 
        INNER join field_data_field_koppla_givare ON node.nid = field_data_field_koppla_givare.field_koppla_givare_nid;

    CREATE VIEW givargrupp_titel AS
        SELECT 
        node.title AS Givargrupp_Titel,
        field_data_field_koppla_givare.entity_id, 
        node.nid 
        FROM node 
        INNER join field_data_field_koppla_givare ON node.nid = field_data_field_koppla_givare.entity_id;
```

Then I use these views in this query and add a couple of select items (apologies for the long table names):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
instrumenttitel.InstrumentTitel, 
givargrupp_titel.Givargrupp_Titel, 
givaretitel2.givare_title, 
field_data_field_underrubrik_givare.field_underrubrik_givare_value, 
field_data_field_artikelnr_produkt.field_artikelnr_produkt_value, 
field_data_field_tekniska_data_givare.field_tekniska_data_givare_value 
FROM 
givaretitel2 
Left JOIN instrumenttitel ON givaretitel2.entity_id = instrumenttitel.entity_id 
Left JOIN givargrupp_titel ON givargrupp_titel.entity_id = instrumenttitel.entity_id 
Left JOIN field_data_field_underrubrik_givare ON field_data_field_underrubrik_givare.entity_id = givaretitel2.nid 
Left JOIN field_data_field_artikelnr_produkt ON field_data_field_artikelnr_produkt.entity_id = givaretitel2.nid 
Left JOIN field_data_field_tekniska_data_givare ON givaretitel2.nid = field_data_field_tekniska_data_givare.entity_id 
ORDER BY InstrumentTitel, givargrupp_titel, givare_title, field_underrubrik_givare_value, field_tekniska_data_givare_value
```

This works fine, but I need to achieve the same result without using views. So I have tried using sub select queries and I have spent a couple of hours getting absolutely nowhere... I don't need a detailed wokring query as an answer, just a hint about how to use sub queries in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To use sub-queries inside a MySQL `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM table2) b ON (a.id = b.id)
```

You can effectively replace any `table` reference with a sub query, as long as you then explicitly give an alias to that sub query.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.